# Sometimes new messages in inbox not colored

Tags: bug, global-inbox

So for example I have 3 new replies in my inbox and next to my inbox a number "3" in red glows.

But sometimes all the messages in the inbox are the same color, the three newest should have a slightly different color. Sometimes it does show them in a different color, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: They do have a different colour. What site do you see this on?

Comment: I've edited this into a bug report instead.